# How can I perform an instanceof operation on a member of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, instanceof

First off, I specifically need to use the instanceof operator. I have a base class, Account, and a CheckingAccount that extends Account. I have an ArrayList of accounts; one is a base Account, one is a CheckingAccount, and one is a SavingsAccount. I need to cycle through the ArrayList and call a method that's unique to the CheckingAccount class. Here is my for loop:

```
    for ( Account a : accounts) {
        if (a instanceof CheckingAccount) {
            System.out.println(a.toString()+" "+a.getOverdraftLimit()+" ");
        }
    }
```

a.getOverdraftLimit gives me the error that getOverdraftLimit is not defined for the type Account. My ArrayList was built of Account references. Is there a way I can use the instanceof operator on the call directly? instance of CheckingAccount a.getOverdraftlimit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already checked if it's a `CheckingAccount`, but you still have a reference variable of type `Account` -- `a`.

Cast it to `CheckingAccount` so you can call the method specific to that class.

```
if (a instanceof CheckingAccount) {
    System.out.println(a.toString()+" "+((CheckingAccount) a).getOverdraftLimit()+" ");
}
```

A more object oriented approach would be the following:

Override `toString()` in `CheckingAccount`.  Have that method return the overdraft limit as part of the returned string, so that it's not necessary to cast an `Account` to a `CheckingAccount` just to call `getOverdraftLimit`.

Comment: I actually did override toString(), we are learning about inheritance right now and we are supposed to do it this way so that we are forced to use instanceof. I agree, your approach would be much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a cast on `a` in order to use `CheckingAccount` methods:

```
System.out.println(a.toString()+" "+((CheckingAccount)a).getOverdraftLimit()+" ");
```

It's pretty common to declare a new variable for that purpose, especially if it would be used more than once:

```
CheckingAccount checking = (CheckingAccount)a;
System.out.println(checking.toString()+" "+checking.getOverdraftLimit()+" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `a` to `CheckingAccount` (since you know it is one) and then call the method.

```
CheckingAccount ca = (CheckingAccount)a;
ca.getOverdraftLimit(); //no error.
```